# How to use pgdb.executemany?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, parameters, pgdb

I'm trying to execute `insert` statements from Python to PostgreSQL using the pgdb module.

I see the documentation says:

```
    cursor.executemany(query, list of params)
    # Execute a query many times, binding each param dictionary
    # from the list.
```

So I'm trying things like:

```
>>> insert = "insert into foo (name, number) values (?,?);"
>>> params = [{ 'name': 'John', 'number': 123 }, { 'name': 'Jack', 'number': 234 }]
>>> cursor.executemany(insert, params)
```

This is giving me a error, pointing at the `?`. What is the correct syntax for this sort of parameterized query? Also, if this is in the documentation, where do I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want

```
insert = "insert into foo (name, number) value (%(name)s, %(number)s);"
```

Which style for parameter inclusion is supported by your DBAPI driver can be found with the `paramstyle` module-level constant. According to the [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) (aka python database API 2 specification):

> String constant stating the type of parameter marker
>   formatting expected by the interface. Possible values are
>   [2]:
>
> ```
> 'qmark'         Question mark style, 
>                 e.g. '...WHERE name=?'
> 'numeric'       Numeric, positional style, 
>                 e.g. '...WHERE name=:1'
> 'named'         Named style, 
>                 e.g. '...WHERE name=:name'
> 'format'        ANSI C printf format codes, 
>                 e.g. '...WHERE name=%s'
> 'pyformat'      Python extended format codes, 
>                 e.g. '...WHERE name=%(name)s'
> ```

and if you check pgdb, you'll see that

```
>>> import pgdb
>>> pgdb.paramstyle
'pyformat'
```